# Why backhub taking only master branch of repositories?

Tags: github

I have 2 repositories where 1 repository named Web has 4 branches.

The issue when is taking backup i see only main branch data is been backed up. How to backup all the branches data of that repository?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you copy your git repositories to somewhere else you will have all remote branches and pull requests in there. basically that is all stored in the hidden `.git` directory which is inside every repository.

The reason why you only see the main branch is because that is the default branch you are currently on.

You can list all branches with `git branch -a` inside the backup repository. Without being connected to the internet! Because you already have all needed data in the backup.

Now you can `git checkout the-other-remote-branch-name` to see or use the state of that branch from when the backup was created.

Comment: i couldn't; see .git directory in downloaded zip file from backhup, where as in local when i have cloned git with uri i can see that .git not in zip

Comment: @goodyzain what are the steps you use to take the backup?

Comment: firstly i have installed backhub and given access to backup in github setting Repository access : selected 2 repos, i have added backhub image from where i am getting the zip file

Comment: @goodyzain ok, I had no idea you use a tool called backhub for that. You should update your question containing that information. I don't know anything about that tool, so I can not help you with this.